# Select view columns from subselect (oracle, sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, oracle12c

I got select:

```
select c.ColA, c.ColB, c.ColC, c.ColD from table1 c
where c.ColB in (
                select colX from table2 where colZ in ('test', 'test2') and colV = 3
                );
```

How can I also display **ColV** from table2?

When I doing as:

```
c.ColB in (select colX, colV from table2 where colZ in ('test', 'test2') and colV = 3)
```

*I got error*: 00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do an inner join in this case:

```
SELECT c.colA, c.colB, c.colC, c.colD, c2.colV
  FROM table1 c INNER JOIN table2 c2
    ON c.colB = c2.colX
 WHERE c2.colZ IN ('test', 'test2')
   AND c2.colV = 3;
```

As a rule of thumb use a `JOIN` condition when you need columns from another table; use `EXISTS` or `IN` when you don't.

Hope this helps.

P.S. The qualifier `INNER` is unnecessary but I like it because it makes things explicit.

Comment: great explanation @David, I have understood completely now, many thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks!